# how to get the port of an ip address?

Tags: c, ip, port

I got a challenge from my teacher today. He gave us an IP number of a server that we need to send our name to by a socket. So, my qestion is how can I find the port number only with the IP?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "find the port number"; maybe show what your teacher provided?

Comment: You will have to use a port scanner to find the ports that are open. then you will have to try and send your name to all of those ports

Answer (score 1):

[Try scanning](http://mxtoolbox.com/PortScan.aspx) the given ip and look for open ports that speaks to you, or just try sending your message to each open port.